# Nginx and Expo's web-build app returns 404

Tags: react-native, nginx, expo

I have this application divided in frontend and backend. Frontend is in react native (using expo) and backend is in Laravel. I used `expo build:web` to build the webapp and deployed it on an AWS server along with the backend.

I made two configuration files: **front** and **back**. **Front** should answer to location `/` while **back** should answer to anything starting with `/api/`.

I managed to get **front** work and then started to work on **back**. As soon as i managed to make my first api call the **front** stopped working. The strange thing is that it's not nginx default 404 error, it's expo's. You can even see the its favicon.

My config files:

Backend (working)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    root /var/www/app/hen-backend/public;

    server_name 3.65.210.19;

    location /api/ {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;

    }
}
```

Frontend (Not Working)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    root /var/www/webapp/web-build/;

    server_name 3.65.210.19;

    location / {

        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;


        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;

    }

}
```

Why is it behaving like this? Am I missing something?